# jaxb unmarshaling a list of derived objects

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm trying to unmarshal a list of objects that derive from a common base class.
They are defined as this:

```
public abstract class Par {
  @XmlTransient
  public String name;

  @XmlAttribute(name="name")
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String n) {
    name = n;
  }
}

@XmlRootElement(name="int")
public class IntegerPar extends Par {
    @XmlTransient
    public int value;

    @XmlAttribute(name="value")
    public int getValue() {
      return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int v) {
      value = v;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name="string")
public class StringPar extends Par { ... }
```

Now, if I create a List and marshal it to xml, it works as expected producing a neat

```
<root>
  <int name="x" value="1"/>
  <string name="s" value="hello"/>
</root>
```

but if I want to unmarshal that same xml into this class

```
@XmlRootElement(name="root")
public class ParamRequest {
  @XmlAnyElement
  public ArrayList<Par> params;
}
```

I get the following (taken from eclipse debug)

```
myRequest.params    [[int: null], [string: null]]
```

Any help?
Thanks.

EDIT: The unmarshaling is done by Jersey

```
@POST @Path("/params")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public String postParams(ParamRequest myRequest) {
    myRequest...
    ...
}
```

Comment: both properties are `transient`

Comment: shouldn't it use the setXxx() methods then?
I tried removing the XmlTransient part anyway, and still doesn't work. In addition, the marshaling stopped working as well because there are now 2 properties with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Use [@XmlSeeAlso](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSeeAlso.html) to let know the JAXB about the subclass during marshall/unmarshall.

```
@XmlSeeAlso({IntegerPar.class,StringPar.class})
public abstract class Par {
```

Comment: Still doesn't work.

I don't know if it's important at this point, but I'm using the automatic unmarshaling of Jersey. (added in question)